# What's the correct version of FOSRestBundle to use with Symfony 2.0.18?

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to upgrade my Symfony2 application from 2.0.16 to 2.0.18. I ran into something that looked like a FOSRestBundle problem, so I upgraded FOSRestBundle too (to their latest commit on their master branch), but that seems to cause different problems. Before we go detailing all of that and troubleshooting, can someone just tell me which version of FOSRestBundle could be reasonably expected to work with Symfony 2.0.18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [latest master version of FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/commit/c94952536a85872e3b168d9e6042a9e081255790) appears to work fine with Symfony 2.0.18.

I unpinned FOSRestBundle by removing it from my `deps.lock` file and all is well.

Here's the error I ran into before upgrading FOSRestBundle:

```
PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of FOS\RestBundle\Routing\Loader\RestXmlCollectionLoader::getXmlErrors() should be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\XmlFileLoader::getXmlErrors() in /home/adamm/git/bv-bundles/SingleServerApplication/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/Routing/Loader/RestXmlCollectionLoader.php on line 137
```

I *was* using FOSRestBundle version d9a876803df61858ce3e8d3f0c934727638ad874.